# How to get object from Google cloud storage bucket

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I have used this below code for get object from google cloud storage bucket.i have error in `getMetadata`. Can  any one please tell me here what is `getMetadata` and how to get that ?

```
Storage.Objects.Get getObject = client.objects().get(bucketName, objectname);

            if (getMetadata == true) {
              StorageObject object = getObject.execute();

            } else {
              // Downloading data.
              ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              // If you're not in AppEngine, download the whole thing in one request, if possible.
              getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
              getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running through the [sample code snippet](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get); in that snippet, `getMetadata` is simply referring to your own choice of whether you want to view the object's metadata like size, content-type, creation time, etc., or whether you actually want to download the object's contents.

In your actual code using it, you probably won't structure it that way using any `getMetadata` variable. Instead, you should just use the code from the branch of that conditional that you need in each particular circumstance. For example, if you just want to get the size of the object so that you can display the number of bytes somewhere without actually downloading it:

```
Storage.Objects.Get getObject = client.objects().get(bucketName, objectname);
StorageObject object = getObject.execute();
System.out.println("Size is: " + object.getSize().longValue());
```

Or if you just wanted to dump the contents to `System.out`:

```
Storage.Objects.Get getObject = client.objects().get(bucketName, objectname);
getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(System.out);
```